# Using HostListener in angular to manipulate parent elements properly

Tags: angular, dom-events, angular-directive

I still have some plain-js/jquery thinking in my head and struggling to get the 'angular way' to handle this.

The premise is that I have this type of structure:

```
<div ContainerBox class="draggableContainer">
    <div>
        <div DragHandle class="dragHandle">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(note, the HTML for ContainerBox is in one component template, the HTML for DragHandle is in a different component template)

The goal here is to make `ContainerBox` movable on screen when a user clicks and drags on the child element `DragHandle`

I initially set up a directive using `[DragHandle]` as the selector. This allows me to set a `mousedown` HostListener to determine when a user has clicked on that object.

But...I don't see a clean 'angular way' to now change the css of the div two parents up. I suppose I could create a JS function that grabs the parent, checks for a matching class name of 'draggableContainer' and if so, done, if not, grabs the parent of that element, checks again, and so on until it finds the parent that matches. But that feels messy.

Alternatively, I could apply my directive to the `[ContainerBox]` via setting the selector. On mousedown, I could then check for the `event.target` accordingly. But I'm not sure that's the best way either.

Are either of these options a better way to go? Or is there another, more 'angular-like' way to handle this logic?

Comment: Have you looked into just using [the drag/drop CDK module](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) that would probably make life easier?

Comment: Ditto what Chris said, you can’t get more “angular”than cdk

Comment: +1 on the library recommendation, but in short, your `ContainerBox` will receive data through `@Input` and your `DragHandle` will send events up the tree through `@Output` and `EventEmitter`.

Comment: If you wanted to stick with the current method I'd suggest [a service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) over `@Input`/`@Output` chains.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use parent container component and child to operate. But if you need just in code as wrote:

```
<div containerBox class="draggableContainer" #containerBox="containerBox">
    <div>
        <div class="dragHandle" (click)="containerBox.someAction()" (drag)="containerBox.someAction()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your `containerBox` directive add `someAction` method or something like this. Important mark is to set `exportAs: 'containerBox'` in `@Directive` decorator.

In other case you can work with you `containerBox` element as HTMLElement:

```
<div containerBox class="draggableContainer" #containerBox>
    <div>
        <div class="dragHandle" (click)="...containerBox here is HTMLElement... you can change any style or class, and more...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```